# Installing compilers on Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I have a C project that I'd like to be tested on multiple different C compilers. I'm currently testing it using Azure Pipelines, but I'm not sure what the best way to add more compilers to my workflow.

Currently, I just use a script to `sudo apt install` a few other things I need for testing, but Azure warns me not to do this. I also run into a problem where the latest version of TCC isn't available through `apt install`, so I currently can't test that through my current method.

Is there a proper way to do this? I'm thinking maybe specify a VM for Azure to use, onto which I've already installed whatever software I need. I have no idea if this is possible or how to do it though. Looking through the Azure Pipelines documentation hasn't been very helpful either since I don't know what I'm looking for.

(Please let me know if anything is not clear, I'm not 100% sure of the proper terminology surrounding this.)

EDIT: I basically want to be able to add something like this to my `azure-pipelines.yml`:

```
- job: 
  displayName: "C TCC Ubuntu"
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - script: |
      set -e
      cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=tcc .
      make
    displayName: "Compile"
  - script:
      ./tests
    displayName: "Run Tests"
```

except with the `vmImage` being a custom one onto which I've already installed `tcc`. In case that's not possible, any other sort of work-around is also appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure DevOps pipelines has two models for agents, self-hosted or hosted. You could run a self-hosted agent that you preinstall your tool chain. That brings without management of that server and the cost of it sitting idle. To do self-hosted [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) are the docs that walk you through the installation.

I would encourage you to use the hosted agents as it gives you the most flexibility and doesn't limit you to just one operating system to execute your build against if you so desire. With that said, the common pattern with the hosted agents are to install your tools in a task like you have said you are doing. The Azure DevOps Extension marketplace has several examples of people creating extensions to install tools. [Here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=spontoreau.rust-vsts) is an example for Rust, notice the installer screenshot.

If you don't want to incur the penalty of installing your compiler on every build, you could also leverage the ability of the hosted agents to use a container to build your software. You could then prebuild a container image that has your compiler and other tools installed and instruct Azure DevOps to use that in the hosted agent to do your compilation. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases) is that documentation.